# How do I get a precompiled linux binary for protoc ( protocol buffers )?

Tags: java, ant, protocol-buffers

My build server is linux based. I need protoc to integrate it to my ant based build system.

I use following in build.xml for same:

```
    <exec executable="tools/protoc.exe" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="--java_out=../protos/java/generated" />
        <arg value="--proto_path=../protos/proto" />
        <arg value="../protos/proto/*.proto" />
    </exec>
```

I found windows binary , but didn't find linux binary for protoc.

Any help to find one or build statically linked protoc binary would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried just downloading the [main protobuf project](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list) and following the [installation instructions](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL.txt)? I seem to remember it's pretty straightforward if you only need the binary:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
```

(You probably don't need `make install` in this case, if you only need the `protoc` binary. Just find out where it's been built and copy it.)

Comment: isn't protoc dependent on other libraries ? will this protoc binary work with various linux versions in development env. ?

Comment: @YoK: I *believe* `protoc` is statically linked in terms of dependencies. Whether a single binary will work with various linux versions will no doubt depend on the combinations you're talking about - but it's probably worth at least trying.

Comment: hmmm it that case only way I see is... each developer would need to build protoc. but we build protoc for build server and check it in.

Comment: @YoK: How many different versions of Linux do your developers use? You might want to try it on a few "common" configurations...

Comment: There is no such thing as **./configure** in that project.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: I suspect there was 5 years ago... but now you need to run `./autogen.sh` first. Have edited the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet When I run `./autogen.sh`, I get this error: **line 48: autoreconf: command not found**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Well have you installed all the tools listed in https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I am on a Mac.  So I needed: **sudo xcode-select --install**

Answer (score 3):

Precompiled binaries for the latest release are on the official [releases page](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases) on GitHub. Previous versions can be found on the [Maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/).

Comment: No, there are no **protoc** binaries in those folders.

Comment: Documentations says that they need to be there, but I also haven't found protoc binary

Answer (score 1):

For java you also could use https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar which already contains binaries for different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (since 12.04) you can find `protobuf-compiler` in the repository.

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler

$> protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

And you might as well want to install the header files:

```
sudo aptitude install libprotobuf-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to compile only `protoc` binary for *any platform*, then follow these steps:

Under protobuf project directory

```
./autogen.sh
cd protoc-artifacts
./build-protoc.sh linux x86_64 protoc
```

Once, the `protoc.exe` is built in `protobuf/protoc-artifacts/target/linux/x86_64/protoc`
rename it to `protoc`

```
mv protobuf/protoc-artifacts/target/linux/x86_64/protoc.exe protobuf/protoc-artifacts/target/linux/x86_64/protoc
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Download binary from the url  https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

2) extract and keep the directory at particular location (`/user/app/protoc`)

3) add the entry in /usr//.bash_profile as

```
export PROTOC_HOME=/user/app/protoc
export PATH=$PROTOC_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

4) refresh file  `$source /usr/<username>/.bash_profile`

Other option is run the following command one by one after downloading the repository :

```
sudo rm -rf ./protoc
unzip protoc-3.10.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc
chmod 755 -R protoc
BASE=/usr/local
sudo rm -rf $BASE/include/google/protobuf/
sudo cp protoc/bin/protoc $BASE/bin
sudo cp -R protoc/include/* $BASE/include
```